# Freeing up space inside a method

Tags: c#

Let's say I create a big `Dictionery` or `List` object in my method so at that point the `varible` that holds this list has many items in it and so it takes a large amount of memory. So now somewhere in the middle of my method I am done with this varaible and don't need it anymore but still I am doing other things in my method so I am not like quickly getting out of the scope of the method so to save some memory if I set that variable to `null`, does that save up on memory?

Comment: your method is too large

Comment: Unless you see an actual performance hit *and* can track it down specifically to this, you may be trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: If you're defining a large variable, and then not using it in your whole method, that sounds like a smell suggesting some refactoring to pull some functionality into a separate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A local variable is eligible for garbage collection after it is last used. Scope has nothing to do with being eligible for garbage collection, setting it to `null` won't do anything useful.

So much so, that the variables `input` and `result` in the next code snippet are likely to occupy the same memory, since their lifetimes don't overlap.

```
void Method(string input)
{
    string result = Process(input);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Read Eric Lippert's [Construction Destruction](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/10/construction-destruction/) and Raymond Chen's [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx)